# Undefined behavior on order of evaluation?

Tags: c++

I came across the [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) page on cppreference and I can't undestand why these lines are considered undefined behavior.

```cpp
i = ++i + 2;       // undefined behavior until C++11
f(i = -2, i = -2); // undefined behavior until C++17
```

In the first case, isn't the `++i` assignment computed and then the sum and then the final assignment to `i`?

How about the second case? It seems to me that the function will get both arguments as `-2` and the value of `i` will always be `-2` after the execution.

Comment: Before C++11, the rule was much simpler:   a statement that modified a variable more than once had undefined behaviour.    Both the statements you give do that, hence undefined behaviour.   C++11 (and later standards) have changed the rules so a number of cases of behaviour that was previously undefined is now either unspecified or well-defined.    In a number of cases (not all) I consider the changes to be dumb moves, since they often implicitly encourage writing more cryptic and hard-to-maintain code - but that's what quite a few people lobbied for.